# Mocking framework in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

There are enough posts about how to use MockK and Mockito, but what's the import difference between them, what's your preference when using a Mocking framework in Kotlin and why?

Answer (score 2):

[MockK](https://mockk.io/) introduces itself as a "mocking library for Kotlin".

[Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) states "Tasty mocking framework for unit tests in Java" (and as a side-note: Mockito existed already before Kotlin).

So, already on the first page you have the most important difference. That being said, if you want to use mocks and you are using Kotlin, I would suggest you look up MockK... if the issues there do not affect you, you are relatively safe. If you are familiar with Mockito and it isn't too cumbersome for you to use with Kotlin (e.g. try to use `when`), then that might be ok too.

(Finally... I don't use mocks anymore... most of the time I find too many things are mocked, that shouldn't even be mocked at all... but those are just my 2 cents here)